# Reshape subsections of Pandas DataFrame into a wide format

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing data from a PDF which has not been optimised for analysis.

The data has been imported into the following dataframe

```
NaN   NaN   Plant_A     NaN     Plant_B      NaN   
Pre   1,2   1.1         1.2         6.1      6.2   
Pre   3,4   1.3         1.4         6.3      6.4
Post  1,2   2.1         2.2         7.1      7.2
Post  3,4   2.3         2.4         7.3      7.4
```

and I would like to reorganise it into the following form:

```
            Pre_1   Pre_2   Pre_3   Pre_4  Post_1   Post_2   Post_3   Post_4  
Plant_A       1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4     2.1      2.2      2.3      2.4
Plant_B       6.1     6.2     6.3     6.4     7.1      7.2      7.3      7.4
```

I started by splitting the 2nd column by commas, and then combining that with the first column to give me `Pre_1` and `Pre_2` for instance. However I have struggled to match that with the data in the rest of the columns. For instance, `Pre_1` with `1.1`  and `Pre_2` with `1.2`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No offense intended but that is terrible.  I'd suggest a different import method or change how the data is stored.  If you are absolutely stuck with that, I'm sorry.  This comment may not be very helpful but I'm hoping that hearing this opinion might validate your own suspicions that this is a bad way to have your data be.

Comment: You also may want to consider going back to your other question and selecting one of the answers others provided for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make some assumptions in regards to consistency of your data

```
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd

tracker = {}

for temporal, spec, *data in df.itertuples(index=False):
  data = data[::-1]
  cycle_plant = cycle(['Plant_A', 'Plant_B'])
  spec_i = spec.split(',')

  while data:
    plant = next(cycle_plant)
    for i in spec_i:
      tracker[(plant, f"{temporal}_{i}")] = data.pop()

pd.Series(tracker).unstack()

         Post_1  Post_2  Post_3  Post_4  Pre_1  Pre_2  Pre_3  Pre_4
Plant_A     2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4    1.1    1.2    1.3    1.4
Plant_B     7.1     7.2     7.3     7.4    6.1    6.2    6.3    6.4
```